# Laravel mix enable hash for css and js files

Tags: laravel

How I can enable hash for css and js files, compiled by laravel mix?
Example I need do:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}?hash=3234234" rel="stylesheet">
```

For clear cache, when file is changed. How I can do it?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using versioning with your static asset you have to use `mix()` it will do the versioning automatically for you.

```
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

And while mixing use `.version()` too.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .version();
```

From the Docs

> If you won't know the exact file name. So, you should use Laravel's global mix function within your views to load the appropriately hashed asset. The  mix function will automatically determine the current name of the hashed file

Comment: @Dumitru post your mixing script too